# How to specify a daemon shutdown command with upstart?

Tags: upstart

In an upstart configuration how do I define what command should be used to shutdown a server. Lets say I have daemon that has two seperate processes.

- startup.sh  - to start the server
- shutdown.sh - to shut down the server

Suppose I have an upstart file that looks like this.

```
description "Some Example Service"
author "Me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn

exec startup.sh
```

How do I tell upstart that it should call `shutdown.sh` when shutting down the server? How does upstart normally expect to shut down a daemon?

Answer (score 10):

Using `exec` to start the process is fine, but when stopping it, if you absolutely need to run a specific script or set of commands, you can use the  `pre-stop` stanza.

```
pre-stop exec shutdown.sh
```

I assume you have tried just using an exec stanza and it didn't work, possibly because your daemon requires some specialized cleanup. Note that well-behaved daemons should receive a signal from upstart when the job is stopped, and if they handle the signal appropriately no additional cleanup should be needed.

> Stopping a job involves sending SIGTERM to it. If there is anything
>   that needs to be done before SIGTERM, do it here. Arguably, services
>   should handle SIGTERM very gracefully, so this shouldn't be necessary.
>
> if there is anything critical, like a flush to disk, and raising kill
>   timeout is not an option, pre-stop is not a bad place to do it

Also read [this section](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id116) for the entire workflow of what happens when you stop a job. Notice when pre-stop is run, and how a signal is sent to the process afterwards, which is how upstart handles stopping jobs normally.

My source is the official Upstart cookbook at: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: "Note that well-behaved daemons should receive a signal from upstart when the job is stopped, and if they handle the signal appropriately no additional cleanup should be needed." - note that we use scripts in Unix world in order to have control of things beside programers job. And this is ridiculous remark, because we need a place to include for example sending an email, removing lock from the dis etc. and this tasks do not have to be part o daemon itself. So upstart is not ready to be used into servers environment.

Comment: From this answer ( the One!) i see that there is no good way do do what we need?